# StandBy with every Monitor except one

Tags: boot, screen

I used my RaspPi as a automatic testclient. After a while, the OS crashed and it's not bootable anymore. But thats not the main problem.

I need the Raspberry somewhere else. I changed the location and tried to start it, but every screen I use doesnt work, it's just in the Standby modus.

I also tried to use both connections, DVI and VGA, still the same problem. Then I tried it on my old screen, there it works. I don't know why, I tried every option in my screen settings, I also tried the manual way to choose an input.

Does someone know a solution?

Comment: Which HDMI -> DVI and HDMI -> VGA or Analog -> VGA converter(s) do you use?

Comment: - Did you try an HDMI monitor?
- Did you plug in the HDMI correctly in the pi? [The plug fits entirely in the connector.](http://rayhightower.com/assets/raspberry_pi_iphone.jpg)